# Strip commas from a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

**Input:**

```
$str = "I want to remove only comma from this string, how ?";
```

I want to remove commas from `$str`, I'm new in programming and I don't understand how regex works.

Comment: Have you read a RegEx help or tutorial/ That should answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regex:** `(?<!\d)\,(?!\d)`

`(\,|\.)` for matching exact either `,` or `.`

`(?!\d)`  should not contains digits ahead.

`(?<!\d)` should not contains digit behind.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php

$str = "I want to remove only comma from this string, how. ? Here comma and dot 55,44,100.6 shouldn't be removed";
echo preg_replace("/(?<!\d)(\,|\.)(?!\d)/", "", $str);
```

**Output:**

```
I want to remove only comma from this string how ? Here comma 55,44,100 shouldn't be removed
```

Comment: can you explain to me what is `/(?<!\d)\,(?!\d)/` ?

Comment: hey, now I also want to remove all `.`. I can do it with `str_replace`, but i have to write it in new line. How can I make it just in one line code ?

Comment: Do you want to replace `,` and `.` without str_replace?

Comment: yeah, is it possible ? is `str_replace` the only way to do it ?

Comment: @kurniawan26 Updated my post you can check valid dots and comma are replaced without interrupting digits

Comment: @kurniawan26 Welcome... :) I love to help

Answer (score 4):

use **[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)**.

Example

```
$str = "I want to remove only comma from this string, how ?";
$str = str_replace(",", "", $str);
```

**Explaination**

As you can see there is 3 arguments we pass in str_replace

1. "**,**" => this one is what you want to replace
2. "" => this one is value that will replace first argument value. we pass blank so it will replace comma to blank
3. this one is string where you want to replace.